# C++ value evaluation in concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

#### How to properly evaluate a value in concept declaration / requires clauses ?

Considering a concept `is_red` which check if a given type has a `color` static cx member set to `/*undefined*/::red`, where `/*undefined*/ in an enum;

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept is_red = requires(T) {
   { T::color == decltype(T::color)::red };
};
```

This is obviously wrong, as it only checks if the synthax is well-defined.
Thus, this will not work as expected :

```cpp
namespace apple {
   enum colors{red, green, yellow };

   struct granny_smith{
      constexpr static auto color = colors::green;
   };
}

static_assert(is_red<apple::granny_smith>); // should fail, but it does not using the previous concept implementation
```

See live example on [godbolt here](https://godbolt.org/z/4TMbeshaf).

Here is the way I currently evaluate values in concepts :

```cpp
template <bool condition>
using if_t = std::conditional_t<condition, std::true_type, std::false_type>;

template <typename T>
concept is_red = requires(T) {
   { if_t<(T::color == decltype(T::color)::red)> } -> std::same_as<std::true_type>;
};
```

Which works fine, but looks a bit odd.

Perhaps there is another - cleaner - way to deal with value evaluation in C++ concepts ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A concept can take an arbitrary boolean expression on the right-hand side. A *requires-expression* is just one such boolean expression, but it doesn't have to be that. You can write a comparison directly:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept is_red = T::color == decltype(T::color)::red;
```